# How to read the content of video file and view via <video> tag

Tags: php, linux

My system allows the user uploads videos .mp4 to server. 
The directory of website project is `/var/www/public_html`
Video files are placed at `/sav/videos/`

Now I want to play video in my website, but I can not find any solutions to solve.

Thanks a lot for any useful help.

Comment: Have you tried a `<video>` tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: Can it play video in my server? I didn't try but I think its impossible

Comment: You should try. Or be more specific about what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the `<video>`-Tag - have you tried using the minimal setup? This would look like this:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="/sav/videos/your_video.mp4" />
</video>
```

Please provide us your code, if you've tried something like this before.

Comment: The videos are not stored in web directory. I got 404 response `<domain>/sav/video/queue/usr_5536_28122016.mp4 Failed to load resource`

Comment: and if you try a relative path: `<source src="../../../sav/videos/queue/your_video.mp4"`?